# What's the source for this claim that Data ages?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

[This Screenrant article](https://screenrant.com/star-trek-data-body-abilities-hidden-trivia/?v=8&n=f) (sorry) claims that

> Data's physical appearance is programmed to age at the same rate as a human being. This element of his body was likely written in to allow Brent Spiner to portray the character for as long he wanted.

What's the source for this claim?

Comment: Related: [Why is Data so surprised that he's mortal?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71811/31394) and [Could Brent Spiner still play Data?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28257/31394) [closed].

Comment: There’s at least one line in the show that directly says he does, and another that directly says he doesn’t, There are also plot points that make no sense if he does, and plot points that make no sense if he doesn’t.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know what ScreenRant used for their source, but the following appears in TNG episode ["Inheritance"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/262.htm) (emphasis mine):

> LAFORGE: Basically she's a **Soong-type android**, except everything about her is designed to fool you into thinking she's human.
>   CRUSHER: She's got tear ducts, sweat glands, even veins and capillaries underneath her skin.
>   RIKER: Why does the scanner read her as a human?
>   CRUSHER: Because she has a feedback processor designed to send out a false bio-signal.
>   LAFORGE: It's part of her aging programme. **Not only does she age in appearance like Data**, her vital signs change too.

See also [Jack B Nimble's excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/124156/31394) to a different question.

The second sentence of your quote appears to be ScreenRant's own speculation ("likely"), so I don't think we need to find a proper source for that one.

Comment: That's surprising.  I was expecting this to be something a fan made up with no evidence.

Comment: Wow.. Just Wow!

Comment: Which could be awkward if Data had survived to an extremely advanced age.

Comment: It's also possible that Data has control of his aging subroutine, like he does over his hair growth. It would allow him to grow old with friends, then become young again to make new ones.

Comment: I disagree. This doesn't prove for a second that Data ages in the same manner.

Comment: @HamSandwich, what do you mean?   The quote says Tainer ages in appearance like Data.

Comment: @Xantec There are two pieces of evidence in favor of this theory that I can think of. When his head is sent back in time five hundred years (Yes, I know.) it’s quickly restored to its pristine appearance. And his android daughter, Lal, is given the opportunity to choose her own appearance, including her apparent age. It’s at least well within the capabilities of Federation technology to make an android look younger.

Comment: @Xantec That theory would also explain another problem: why are both Lore and B4, who we know were not created the same year as Data and who spent many years deactivated while Data was active, so physically identical that not even their best friends or own creator can tell them apart? Lore has no desire to be more like humans, but he might have changed his appearance to better impersonate Data. The Romulans might have hoped to use B4 as a spy who could pass as Data. (If so, that backfired spectacularly.)

Comment: Added more references and pictures for and against the theory that he ages.

Comment: Emphasis should be on the "except".  I think this may be a case of a misplaced comma.  If the transcript was instead "Not only does she age in appearance - like Data her vital signs change too."  the line would firmly be against Data aging. We know Data has enough fluid that the water-alcohol virus affects him - he likely has something equivalent to a pulse and blood pressure.  And to borrow from @Davislor answer "Julian Bashir make a guest appearance just to say how surprised he is that Data has working circulatory and respiratory systems that he doesn’t really need."

Comment: @lucasbachmann Fanon is that Data acted like he was affected by the virus in “The Naked Now” because he thought all the new friends he’d just met were doing some strange human thing, so he went along with it.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Anyway, Levar Burton’s line reading sounds to me like he pauses after, not before, “like Data”

Comment: @Davislor I think either the writer or Mr. Burton messed the line up with a missing period or pause.  As I gave credit to you- Data has a number of functions that are similar to life.  The point of the conversation between Crusher and LaForge is to remind the viewer of that. A Soong android isn't just a brain - it's micropumps too. Not drop an atomic bomb revelation that Data ages - especially since he doesn't.  Regarding your Fanon comment I've never heard that, given how dire the situation was quite absurd for anyone to think - especially as Data gave a reasonable explanation in the episode

Answer (score 10):

There are a few lines in the series where Data seems to say that he does not age. In “Measure of a Man,” he responds to small talk asking how he is by saying, “My condition does not alter with the passage of time, Commander.”  In context, he might mean his emotional condition or lack thereof.  But he is usually quite literal.

In “Data’s Day,” he discusses with Troi the possibility that he will marry, but expresses one concern: “I believe I have much to offer a potential mate. However, we cannot grow old together because I will not grow old.”¹  (The writers named him a “positronic” android after Asimov’s, and might have been thinking of *The Positronic Man* here.)  What the question is asking, though, is whether Data superficially looks like he’s getting old.  He would know that’s not the same thing at all.

In the alternative timelines of “All Good Things,” Data and Q are the only characters not to visibly age at all in past, present or future.  Here is what he looks like twenty-five years into one possible future:

[image: Data in an Alternative Timeline]

Brent Spiner has also said that, in his opinion, his character should not age as he has.  It is possible to interpret what we see on screen either literally, so that Data ages like the actor who plays him, or to suspend our disbelief and tell ourselves that Data always looked the same.

There is also a direct quote (as mentioned by Rand al'Thor) stating that he does appear to age as a human: "Not only does she age in appearance like Data, ...."  This is from "Inheritance."

**Spoiler for “Inheritance:”**

> The context in which the characters are discussing how positronic androids age is the revelation that Data’s “mother” was replaced by a positronic android decades ago, unbeknownst to everyone, including herself. This would only be possible if she aged without making any conscious effort to disguise herself.  The writers then decided to explain away the fact that years had passed since Data claimed not to age, and Brent Spiner visibly had.

It’s not just that one episode, though. (There are a lot of things that happen in one episode of *Star Trek* and are never mentioned again that fans just ignore.)  The writers repeatedly made an effort to explain away the fact that Data is played by a human actor who breathes, blinks and ages. “Birthright: Part I” has Julian Bashir make a guest appearance just to say how surprised he is that Data has working circulatory and respiratory systems that he doesn’t really need.  (By the end of that episode, Data even sleeps and dreams, when he wants to.)  The in-universe explanation for why we can see Data blink and breathe and look a decade older is, “Your creator went to a lot of trouble to make you seem human.”

In “Brothers,” Data has a conversation with Dr. Noonian Soong, about why Soong created him, that, if you interpret Data as being designed to age, goes into Soong’s motivations:

> **SOONG:** If you brought a Noophian to Earth, he'd probably look around and say, tear that old village down, it's hanging in rags. Build me something new, something efficient. But to a human, that old house, that ancient wall, it's a shrine, something to be cherished. Again, I ask you, why?
>
> **DATA:** Perhaps, for humans, old things represent a tie to the past.
>
> **SOONG:** What's so important about the past? People got sick, they needed money. Why tie yourself to that?
>
> **DATA:** Humans are mortal. They seem to need a sense of continuity.
>
> **SOONG:** Ah hah! Why?
>
> **DATA:** To give their lives meaning. A sense of purpose.

Soong goes on to lead Data into realizing that humans also have children to maintain this continuity with the future.  When Data himself created an android daughter, in “The Offspring,” she had complete freedom to choose her own appearance, including her age.

This explanation doesn’t work perfectly when we stop to really think about it: Data’s identical brothers Lore and B4 always look exactly the same age as he, even though they were built years apart and both had been shut down for many years while Data was active. This isn’t just the makeup staff forgetting to make them look different ages, either: they look identical in-universe even to the people who know them best and often pull wacky twin shenanigans.  Then there’s that two-parter where Data’s head was left in an underground cave for five hundred years.  That’s a thing that happened.  (*There are a lot of things that happen in one episode ....*)  We can invent explanations (Maybe both Lore and B4 were cosmetically altered to exactly match the appearance of Data, as both Lore and B4’s Romulan manipulators had a motive to do.  Maybe the people who fell for it just weren’t paying good enough attention, etc.) but none is ever given.

If we want to try to reconcile all this into a coherent story, what’s probably going on is that Data does age naturally, and the technology of his time can change his appearance as it could Lal’s (for example, to look like a Romulan).  In the alternative timeline where he became Lucasian professor of physics at Cambridge and lost touch with his friends from Starfleet, he chose to look younger, and in the Prime timeline of *Generations* through *Nemesis*, he chose to age along with his friends.

Out-of-universe, one person who isn’t buying that it makes sense for an android to age like Brent Spiner because he’s a great enough actor to sell it is Brent Spiner.  When asked whether he’ll ever play the role again, he’s repeatedly said [things like:](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/1527439/brent-spiner-says-hed-never-play-data-again-heres-why)

> I think I'd look ridiculous in that makeup now, because I'm just too old for that part. **And he shouldn't age...** I can't play him anymore, that would be silly.

[And also:](https://trekmovie.com/2011/06/29/brent-spiner-talks-typcasting-death-of-data-bringing-back-soong-for-star-trek-sequel/)

> I don’t think that could happen. Look at me. I am a shockingly older gentleman. I don’t see that I could wear that makeup anymore. I think that would look really stupid. I love the character and I wish I started it much younger, but I was already in my mid sixties when I started [joke]. I just don’t think I could get away with it. Yeah they could CGI it, but why not just CGI the whole character and forget about me.

He has *voice-acted* Data since then, in the series finale of *Enterprise*, and played an ancestor of the Dr. Soong who built Data to look like his younger self, but not appeared as Data.

Just two weeks ago, though (August 11, 2018), Brent Spiner [was asked at a convention](http://www.adventuresinpoortaste.com/2018/08/11/star-trek-the-next-generations-brent-spiner-weighs-in-on-cbs-all-accesss-upcoming-captain-picard-series/) whether he would be appearing in the upcoming show about Picard, and facetiously did an impression of Patrick Stewart saying, “I cannot do this show… without Brent Spiner.”  He then clarified that, “I haven’t heard anything about it other than that Patrick announced it in Vegas that he’s doing it,” but he was as excited to hear the news as we were.  So, it’s possible he might change his mind.  He has publicly shared an idea for how Data could come back from the dead if Spiner ever did want to reprise the role.

¹ Thanks to @KevinO for finding this quote!

Comment: This is a great summary, but I know all this-- and it doesn't answer the question.  Even if Juliana Tainer ages, that is far from establishing that Data does.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Added a quote where Data says he *doesn't* age. Hope that answers the question more directly.

Comment: @ThePopMachine I have to disagree about it being far from establishing that Data ages. The line in the episode is, “Not only does she age in appearance like Data, ....”

Comment: Why didn't you include the pivotal line?

Comment: @ThePopMachine The accepted answer already did, and emphasized it.

Comment: I understand, but if you're going to write such a complete treatise, I don't think you skip it just because someone else pointed it out.   It's the pivotal line.   You can give RandalThor attribution if you want.

Comment: @ThePopMachine All right.

Comment: Wasn't there also an episode where Data asks Troi about whether growing old with someone was an important part of a relationship, and then stated he wouldn't age with the person?

Comment: @KevinO It wasn’t “In Theory,” where he did ask Troi and the rest of his friends for relationship advice. And that was the only episode where it rang a bell. Maybe someone else remembers more? But that doesn’t sound definitive: he only superficially appears to age. He knows that’s not the same thing as going through old age with a partner. (No rip-off of *The Positronic Man*.)

Comment: @Davislor, (found it, finally) --  the line I was trying to recall was from "Data's Day." In it he states, "I believe I have much to offer a potential mate. However, we cannot grow old together because I will not grow old." So I think it helps support your initial paragraph. There is also a line in Time's Arrow (?) where he mentions the theoretical possibility he would exist forever, which to me also implies an understanding of agelessness. If he were to actually appear to age as a human, what does a human look like at 3,000 years?

Comment: @KevinO Thanks! I really liked that episode, but had forgotten that line. I think it could be interpreted either way: that he does not age at all, or that he would only appear to, which is not the same thing. I'll add it, however.